# Resize all ListView items to same size

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a list view displaying a list of images from the web. The images are loaded as they are displayed. I also have other items **(non-images)** in the CollectionView of this ListView.

I want all items in the listview to display at the same size, height and width.

All images in the list are the same size, so it works for all of the images in the listview. However other content is not resized to the same size.

I dont know the size of the images beforehand as that could vary, also i must scale the controls to the display size, which is dynamic according to the device used.

How can i achieve this?

edit: i clarified my request

Comment: Do you want to actually resize the physical image before binding, or do you just want to use the img height and width attributes client-side?  And if the proportions are wrong, do you want to crop the images, or have additional white space around it, or stretch/skew the image?

Comment: i do not really care for the images as they already are in the correct size. My problem are the non-image controls in the list. i want them to resize to the same size basically, but i do not want to set a fixed height and width since i cannot decide on a value beforehand (depends on screensize)

Comment: Ahhh Got it.  Thanks!  I'd mis-read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by loading the same image as a background to all items in the list and setting the opacity to 0. This way, all items always have the same size. Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can set the height and the width of these non-image based on the screen size and then bind them.

I really hope I'm making sense here!